# Does `stringify` and `parse` lose round-trip precision from javascript `Number`s in the general case? How about `Number.prototype.toString`?

Tags: javascript, json

I can't find any information on this, but I have the following question: for a number `f` in javascript that's not some NaN, infinite value, or negative zero, do the following statements always evaluate to true:

```js
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(f)) === f;
```

and

```js
Number(f.toString()) === f;
```

With more nuance, is this required by ECMAScript standards? And does this de facto hold among none/some/all the various runtimes?

Comment: Yes, this is guaranteed. They might differ in the particular string through which they roundtrip, but it is required to work for all strings allowed by the specification.